# Reduce array of objects within ES6 function

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused about a reduce function I am working on. I intend to reduce an array of objects, which works just fine, if I declare a variable and set it equal to a reduce iteration:

```js
movies = [
  {
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    rate: '9.3'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather',
    rate: '9.2'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
    rate: '9.0'
  }
  ]
  
const averageRating = movies.reduce((sum, current) => {
    return (sum + parseFloat(current.rate)) / 3;
  }, 0);
  
 console.log(averageRating)
```

However, if I try to write this as ES6 function, it tells me that sum is not defined:

```js
movies = [
  {
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    rate: '9.3'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather',
    rate: '9.2'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
    rate: '9.0'
  }
  ]

ratesAverage = (array) => {
    array.reduce((sum, movies) => {
        return sum + parseFloat(movies.rate);
      }, 0)
}

console.log(ratesAverage(movies))
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Your outer function just doesn't return anything. Add a `return` (or use the shorthand, and just omit the curly braces).

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your arrow function in curly brackets, a `return` statement is required.

Only if you omit the curly brackets, the value of the expression is returned implicitly.

---

```js
movies = [
  {
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    rate: '9.3'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather',
    rate: '9.2'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
    rate: '9.0'
  }
]

ratesAverage = (array) => {
    return array.reduce((sum, movies) => {
        return sum + parseFloat(movies.rate);
      }, 0)
}

console.log(ratesAverage(movies))
```

Answer (score 1):

because you're not returning any value in your function

```
ratesAverage = (array) => {
    return array.reduce((sum, movies) => {
        return sum + parseFloat(movies.rate);
      }, 0)
}
```

just add `return` to the result of `reduce` method.

**or** you can remove the braces to do implicit return

```
ratesAverage = (array) => array.reduce((sum, movies) => {
            return sum + parseFloat(movies.rate);
          }, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When your trying to use `ES6 Arrow function`, try not to use return if your using direct change, because its the one of the advantage of using the arrow function.

For the `reduce`, every iteration, we need to return the value, so it will update in the accumulator, otherwise, it will consider as a undefined.

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more detail info about reduce

You can use the single line of code like below.

```js
movies = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', rate: '9.3' },
  { title: 'The Godfather', rate: '9.2' },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', rate: '9.0' }
];

ratesAverage = list => list.reduce((acc,movie) => ((acc + parseFloat(movie.rate))/3), 0);

console.log(ratesAverage(movies));
```